# Files are avaliable only when they are executable on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, permissions

Videofiles that I copied from windows ntfs partition are only avaliable when they have at least user execution privileges. When I set permissions to 644, I got `Permissions denied`. I even can't to view them by `ls -l`:

```
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? codeschool_194.mp4
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? codeschool_195.mp4
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? codeschool_196.mp4
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? codeschool_197.mp4
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? codeschool_198.mp4
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? codeschool_199.mp4
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? codeschool_200.mp4
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? codeschool_201.mp4
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? codeschool_202.mp4
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? cssxcountry_slides.pdf
```

Comment: what are you asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory you copy the files into does NOT have execute persissions.

From that directory do

```
cd ..
sudo chmod 775 {directoryname}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I set 755 to directories and 644 to files and everything became good!